# Member function a friend

Tags: c++, class, friend

I've been trying some examples in a book (C++ Primer by Stanley Lippman)
and I understand that a class can make another class its friend (to access some private members). Now I'm reading about a member function being a friend and I try the example

```
class Screen
{
public:
    friend void Window_mgr::clear();

    typedef std::string::size_type pos;

    Screen () = default;
    Screen (pos ht, pos wd, char c) : height (ht), width (wd),
                                      contents (ht * wd, c) { }

private:
    void do_display (std::ostream &os) const
    {
        os << contents;
    }

    pos cursor = 0;
    pos height = 0, width = 0;
    pos test_num = 100, test_num2 = 222;;
    std::string contents = "contents";
   };

  class Window_mgr {
 public:
     using ScreenIndex = std::vector<Screen>::size_type;
     void clear (ScreenIndex);

 private:
     std::vector <Screen> screens {Screen (24, 80, ' ')};
 };

 void Window_mgr::clear(ScreenIndex i)
{
Screen &s = screens[i];
s.contents = std::string(s.height * s.width, ' ');
}
```

but it produces a compiler error saying

> Window_mgr has not been declared

and then I read this:

> • First, deﬁne the Window_mgr class, which declares, but cannot deﬁne, clear. Screen must be declared before clear can use the members of Screen.
>
> • Next, deﬁne class Screen, including a friend declaration for clear.
>
> • Finally, deﬁne clear, which can now refer to the members in Screen.

I don't understand this part -- can someone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the compiler gets to `friend void Window_mgr::clear();` it has no idea what `Window_mgr` is as it has not seen that yet.  You need to reorder things around a little to get this to work.  first you forward declare `Screen` and then you have you `Window_mgr`

```
class Screen;

class Window_mgr {
public:
    using ScreenIndex = std::vector<Screen>::size_type;
    void clear(ScreenIndex);
    Window_mgr();

private:
    std::vector <Screen> screens;  // don't initialize here as we don't know what a screen actually is yet
    //std::vector <Screen> screens {Screen (24, 80, ' ')}; can't do this as we don't what a Screen is here
};
```

Then you can have you `Screen` class

```
class Screen
{
public:
    friend void Window_mgr::clear(ScreenIndex);

    typedef std::string::size_type pos;

    Screen() = default;
    Screen(pos ht, pos wd, char c) : height(ht), width(wd),
        contents(ht * wd, c) { }

private:
    void do_display(std::ostream &os) const
    {
        os << contents;
    }

    pos cursor = 0;
    pos height = 0, width = 0;
    pos test_num = 100, test_num2 = 222;
    std::string contents = "contents";
};
```

And then you can have the parts of `Window_mgr` that use `Screen`

```
Window_mgr::Window_mgr() : screens{ Screen(24, 80, ' ') } {}

void Window_mgr::clear(ScreenIndex i)
{
    Screen &s = screens[i];
    s.contents = std::string(s.height * s.width, ' ');
}
```

You can see it all working in this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5fd459766efa2435)

Comment: one thing why did you declare a constructor in Window_mgr

Comment: @KrysselTillada the constructor needed to be declared as you were default creating `screens` in you class declaration and you can't do that as the compiler doesn't know what as `Screen` is at that time.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't think `Screen` is even evaluated in `using ScreenIndex = std::vector<Screen>::size_type;` as it gives to bearing to the result.  AFAIK `size_type` is not type dependent.

Comment: @NathanOliver: As a member it cannot escape being type-dependent, I would have thought... consider specialisations. How can the compiler know what `size_type` and whether it even exists? I suppose any specialisation would have to be in scope by that point and the name is not actually a dependent name... is that really enough? Might post a question about this a bit later on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was trapped by the same code here, but my question is a little bit different. I understand the forward declaration part, my question is that is constructor defined outside class `Window_mgr` the only way to initialize the data member `screens`? (Which means the in class initializer cannot be used here like in your code comment because `Screen` is incomplete type.) Any why an incomplete type can be used as a parameter to the vector template?

Comment: @Jaege If you have a question you should ask a question.  You can link back to this question in your question for reference.

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh, ok :)

Comment: @NathanOliver Would you help me with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34824503/5340808)?

Answer (score 3):

You are most of the way there, you just need to ensure that you declare all of your classes and functions before you require that declaration.

The first instruction point says to define the `Window_mgr` class declaring `Window_mgr::clear`. In order to use `Screen`, that class must also be declared before `Window_mgr`. This looks like:

```
class Screen; //forward-declare Screen so that Window_mgr knows it exists

class Window_mgr {
public:
    //requires forward declaration of Screen, like the above
    using ScreenIndex = std::vector<Screen>::size_type;
    void clear (ScreenIndex); //declare, but don't define, clear
};
```

The second point says to define `Screen` and include a friend declaration for `Window_mgr::clear`. Because that member function has already been declared above, this is valid:

```
class Screen
{
public:
    using ScreenIndex = std::vector<Screen>::size_type;
    //remember to friend with the same arguments
    friend void Window_mgr::clear(ScreenIndex);
    //...
};
```

The final point tells you to now define `Window_mgr::clear`. We have already declared in in the first point, so we just need to do this:

```
void Window_mgr::clear(ScreenIndex i)
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that the signature of your `clear` methods differ.  The one declared in the `Screen` class takes an argument, and the other does not.  Signatures must be identical, or the language actually sees them as different functions.

A second problem is that your implementation conflicts with your first point: "define the `Window_mgr` class, which declares, but cannot define, `clear`."  Your `Window_mgr` class both declares and defines `clear`.